# how do you automate the opening hours from the closing hours in a subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

Hey there I've been struggling with this for a long time anyone could help me it will make my day, I have a subform and on my subform is three fields:
Opening Hours, Closing Hours and Hours Worked
Like my Opening Hours start with 9000 and my Closing hours is 12000 = Hours Worked is 3000
now on the next record in the subform my Opening Hours must automatically become my Closing Hours from the previous record which Opening Hours will become 12000 automatically can anyone help me please as I am under heavy pressure, ill really appreciated thanks in advance. If you can help me with this one youll make my day :)

Answer (score 0):

Is all that information in 1 table and if it is, what is your primary key?

If your using autonumbers.

Just do a dlookup with for exemple :

```
MyPreviousProject = me.IDProject - 1
MyReturn = DLookup("[ClosingHours]", "[TProject]", "[IDProject]=" & MyPreviousProject )
```

Or something like that.

If you need any help just tell me.

Comment: Im not using autonumber my primary key is a text type and Opening Hours and Closing Hours are two different tables any other vba code to do this.Thanks

Comment: How can you know which one is the previous record